# How to arrange table rows in multiline like rowspan but with same color?

Tags: tables

I am working on LaTeX and R. My result in table are in one line (comma seprated) and i want them to be in multiline but within same row (like rowspan).

[image]

I tried to use newline but that does not seems to be working. I also used row span but color of multiline gets changed (automatic alternate coloring).

[image]

In the above figure, I am keeping first line record into multiple line which were comma seprated earlier?  How can I implement it in LaTeX. Any working example will help me a lot.

Comment: Please post some minimal and complete document showing how the table is built at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of possible solutions:

1. You can use `\rownum` to change the color alternancy for particular rows.
2. You can use `\multicolumn` with an appropriate `p{<length>}` specification.

The following code shows the same table three times; the leftmost one exhibits the default color alternancy; the middle one uses the `\rownum` approach, and the rightmost one shows the `\multicolumn` approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors*{1}{blue!60}{blue!20}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
col1 & col2 \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
\end{tabular}\qquad
\rowcolors*{1}{blue!60}{blue!20}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
col1 & col2 \\
\global\rownum=1
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
\end{tabular}\qquad
\rowcolors*{1}{blue!60}{blue!20}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
col1 & col2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}}{text text} & \multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}}{text text} \\
text & text \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Having into account the comment, you can use a `\parbox` of the desired width inside `\multicolumn`, and define a command to simplify the writting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand\boxcolumn[2]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{p{#1}}{\parbox[t]{#1}{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors*{1}{blue!60}{blue!20}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
col1 & col2 \\
\boxcolumn{2cm}{text \\ text} & \boxcolumn{3cm}{text \\ text} \\[2.5ex]
text & text \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if i increase the width of column in cm they appeat to be in same line.\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                               

\begin{document}


\rowcolors*{1}{blue!60}{blue!20}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
col1 & col2 \\multicolumn{1}{p{5cm}}{text text} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5cm}}{text text} \text & text \\end{tabular}

\end{document}  I want to keep still in next line weather width is more or less.

Comment: @manish you can use the `\rownum` approach instead. I added a new option in my edited answer, using a `\parbox` of the desired width.